# chrome のユーザー切り替えのショートカット

Tags: google-chrome

毎度、右上をクリックしてユーザーを選ぶのが面倒に思えてきました。

chrome でキーボードショートカットでユーザーを切り替えるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

もしくはブラウザを使い分けるとか、他に実践している良い方法がありますか？

Answer (score 1):

Windowsであれば「Ctrl + Shift + M」でユーザー切り替えができるようです。

[Chrome のキーボード ショートカット - Google Chrome ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=ja)

Answer (score 0):

Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
Mac: `/Users/(ログインID)/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`

上記のディレクトリに `Profile 1` などの ユーザープロファイル ディレクトリがあります。
これらを `--profile-directory` オプションで指定できます。

`> chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default"`
`> chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

あとは、何かしらのアプリケーションランチャーを導入して、起動すれば良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

利用しているのが Windows であれば、Chrome で複数ユーザーを切り替えて利用するという点で言うと、一旦ユーザーを切り替えた後、当該ユーザーのウィンドウで設定を開くと "ユーザー名 ‣" と表示されないでしょうか。
この部分をクリックするとユーザー名やアイコンの編集以外に "デスクトップショートカットを表示" の on/off 項目がありますので、これを on にするとデスクトップにショートカットが表示されます。("ユーザー名" - Chrome)

これはデスクトップに新しいリンクとして作成されますが、そのままスタートにピン留めすると「デスクトップにあるショートカットをピン留めした」扱いとなるため、%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs 以下にコピーした上で……というのが、タスクバー上に常駐させたいといった場合には良いかもしれません。
デスクトップにアイコンを置いておくだけでいいなら、単に「デスクトップショートカットを表示」だけで良いでしょう。